# How to pass or retrieve last selected div tag id (got through onclick function), in another onclick function using Jquery..?

Tags: jquery, html, css, onclick, flip

I pointed out what i need: (Need help for point 2 & 3)

1. I get the last selected div tag id in onclick function. (solved)
2. While click Flip X option (this is another onclick function), i need to retrieve last selected div tag id.
3. Then in if loop i need to check div with last selected id has class front or not..?

Thanks in Advance....

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
var lastClickedID;

$('.ClickMe').on('click',function()
{
     lastselectedID = $(this).prop('id');
    // alert($(this).prop('id'));
}); 

$('#x').on('click',function()
{         
    if($('div').prop('id',lastselectedID).hasClass('back'))  /* Check img tag with last selected id has class 'back' exist or not */
    {
        $("img").removeClass("back").addClass("front");
    }
    else
    {
        $("img").removeClass("front").addClass("back");
    }
});
});
```

My code in [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/eajdo91a/1/)..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($('#' + lastselectedID).hasClass('back')) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this snippets, you are setting div attribute "id" and check div tag has "back" class or not.

```
$('div').prop('id',lastselectedID).hasClass('back');
```

Use this code:-

```
divId = '#'+lastselectedID;
$(divId).hasClass('back'); // return 1 if "back" class exist or 0 if not exist
```